# Why is nothing going through the filter of my collector

Tags: discord.js

I have tested this using the console.logs, which shows that nothing goes through the filter. I dont know why.

I tried to type in the correct answer, but nothing happened. This is my code

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('gtn')
        .setDescription('Gets a random number 1-100 and the first person to type it wins!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        console.log(`${interaction.user.tag} created a gtn match, with the correct number being ${index}.`);

        interaction.reply('Thinking about a good number...')
                setTimeout(() => {
                    interaction.editReply(`Ok. I have found a good number. It is between 1 and 100. Everyone start guessing!`)
                }, 3000);
        
        const filter = (m) => m.content.startsWith('1') || m.content.startsWith('2') || m.content.startsWith('3') || m.content.startsWith('4') || m.content.startsWith('5') || m.content.startsWith('6') || m.content.startsWith('7') || m.content.startsWith('8') || m.content.startsWith('9')
        var correct = false
        var sent = false
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({time: 10000 });
        collector.on('collect', m => {
            if (correct == false && sent == false)
            {
                setTimeout(() => {
                interaction.send('You ran out of time. Try again to get the correct number.')
                collector.stop()
                }, 10000);
                sent = true
                console.log('lost')
            }
            if (m.content == index)
            {
                correct = true
                interaction.send(`Congratulations! You have guessed the correct number. (${index})`)
                collector.stop()
                console.log('won')
            } 
        });
        collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: You don't use that `filter` anywhere, why do you think something should go through it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your filter in your message collector. Without it, the collector doesn't know what to look for:

```js
const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({ time: 10000, filter });
```